# Package for quiz

Tags: webquiz

I am looking for a package in order to create quizzes.
I’ve seen the exam package and the webquiz package. They look great, but there are in fact document classes, and that’s not what I want. I created chapters in book class and I would like to create a quiz at the end of each chapter (in my main file with all the chapters), so I can’t change document class.
Would there be a package which could suit me?

Comment: Do you want to replicate the functionality of having a bank of questions? That seems a strange feature of a book.  If it's just formatting, then the `exsheets` package is designed to format questions of various sorts.

Comment: There are several similar packages, such as exercise and exesheet.  No opinion on their relative value.  There is also pdfpages to insert one document into another.

Comment: Thank you both. I just want to have environments for true or false, multiple choices, check boxes… I’ll look at exsheets and exercise package

Comment: Can you please add a few examples of such quizzes to your question? In this case screenshots may be just fine. Then we have a better idea. Thank you

Comment: I found the package xsim, and that's the package I will use. Thank you all